# subsonic - convert an linq query to sql query / DataReader

Tags: c#, linq, subsonic, subsonic3

Let's say I have a the following query:

```
int x = 5;
var result = from p in db.products
             where p.CategoryId == x
             select p;

int count = result.Count();
List<product> products = result.ToList();
```

That's what I have now. But aditionally I need to have a DataReader from result:

```
// that's what I need:
var reader = ConvertSubSonicLinqQueryToDataReader(result);
```

How can I convert the linq statement to something I can work with?
A DataReader or a DbCommand or even plain sql with a list of paramters.

I know SubSonic can do that (since it translates the query to plain sql anyway) but I haven't found anything in the public accessible methods yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to do with the DataReader? Maybe there is something we can suggest instead.

Comment: I have to pass a DataReader to a third party method (it would be sufficient to compile the linq query to a plain sql statement so I can use an InlineQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Converting the LINQ query is the wrong approach. LINQ returns results at a level of abstraction higher than a DataReader works at.

There's also the issue of deferred execution so your LINQ query may not be executed as a single SQL statement anyway.

Rater than use a LINQ statement why not just use an `SqlQuery` instead?

```
var qry = new Select().From(Product.Schema).Where(Product.CategoryIdColumn).IsEqualTo(x);

return qry.ExecuteReader();
```

**Edit:**
Just seen you're using SubSonic3 (not 2 as the above code would be for) but the potential misuse of LINQ and duplication of work still stands.

Comment: I know that a Linq Query is a expression in the first place and get's executed if needed (that's why I included two statements, `Count()` and `ToList()` in my example, which results in two different queries). SubSonic must have the capability to convert a specific IQuerable<T> to something like an `IDataReader` or `IDbCommand` because at the end of the day subsonic has to execute it against a dbms. Maybe that method is not in the public interface atm but I'm sure I'll figure it out somehow. Btw. it's hard to explain but I can't use the querytool because I get the IQuerable from another source.

Comment: @SchlaWiener To turn an `IQueryable<T>` into an `IDataReader` is going to take some digging through the source of `SubSonic.core`. I'd start by looking at `SubSonic.Linq.Strucutre.QueryCompiler` and `SubSonic.SqlGenerator`.

Answer (score 0):

The code that creates object from the DataReader can be found in DbDataProvider.ToEnumerable. It's called from DbQueryProvider's Execute method (line 227). The best way to "understand" the LINQ magic is to place some breakpoints on DbQueryProvider methods.